# PDO Insert doesn't work, but other yes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have a problem with my INSERT PDO statements :

In the same PHP page, I have this first INSERT :

```
//Creation d'un entrainement
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['intitule_ent']) && isset($_POST['start_ent'])) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $_POST['intitule_ent'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['intitule_ent']));
    }

    $intitule = $_POST['intitule_ent'];

    if($i = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO entrainements (intitule_entrainement,id_membre) VALUES (:intitule_entrainement,:id_membre)")){
        $i->bindParam(':intitule_entrainement', $intitule);
        $i->bindParam(':id_membre', $user_id);
        $i->execute();
        echo '<span class="label label-success">Entrainement créé avec succès!</span>';
        $entrainement_commence = true;
    }
    else {
        echo '<span class="label label-danger">Erreur lors de la création de l\'entraînement.</span>';
    }
}
```

This INSERT works well!

But the problem is that this INSERT doesn't work :

```
//Verifications d'usage du formulaire et securite
if (isset($_POST['exm']) && isset($_POST['series']) && isset($_POST['repetitions']) && isset($_POST['valider'])) {

    //On securise les chaines de caracteres pour eviter les injections
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $_POST['repetitions'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['repetitions']));
        $_POST['poids'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['poids']));
        $_POST['temps'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['temps']));
        $_POST['force'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['force']));
        $_POST['vitesse'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['vitesse']));
    }

    $id_exom = $_POST['exm'];
    $s = $_POST['series'];
    $r = $_POST['repetitions'];
    $p = $_POST['poids'];
    $t = $_POST['temps'];
    $f = $_POST['force'];
    $v = $_POST['vitesse'];


    if($i = $bdd->prepare("
        INSERT INTO exercices (id_entrainement,id_exercice_muscle,membre,series,reps,poids,temps,force_exo,vitesse)
        VALUES (:id_entrainement,:id_exercice_muscle,:membre,:series,:reps,:poids,:temps,:force_exo,:vitesse)")
        ){

        $i->bindParam(':id_entrainement', $id_ent_en_cours);
    $i->bindParam(':id_exercice_muscle', $id_exom);
    $i->bindParam(':membre', $user_id);
    $i->bindParam(':series', $s);
    $i->bindParam(':reps', $r);
    $i->bindParam(':poids', $p);
    $i->bindParam(':temps', $t);
    $i->bindParam(':force_exo', $f);
    $i->bindParam(':vitesse', $v);
    $i->execute();
    $envoi_succes = '<span class="label label-success">Enregistrement réalisé avec succès !</span>';
}
else {
    $envoi_erreur = '<span class="label label-warning">Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement de l\'exercice.</span>';
}
```

I really don't know why it doesn't work, according to my table schema : 
[image: My table schema]

And here is my DB : 
[image]

I give you here my form, but I think it's not very useful... :

```
<form name="envoi_exo" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="exm" disabled value="">
    <input type="text" name="series" disabled value="">
    <input type="text" name="repetitions" disabled value="">
    <input type="text" name="poids" disabled value="">
    <input type="text" name="temps" disabled value="">
    <input type="text" name="force" disabled value="">
    <input type="text" name="vitesse" disabled value="">
    <button type="submit" name="valider" class="btn btn-success">Enregistrer l\'exercice</button>
</form>
```

And finally, I found on StackOverflow some topics on INSERT problems in PDO, and I tried to find a solutions with try catch (not recommended) and open my MYSQL log file.. Here are the latests logs :

`2015-03-13 21:36:01 6916 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2015-03-13 21:52:57 6916 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2015-03-13 21:52:57 6916 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.`

I really need help to correct this problem because i search solutions again and again, and I found nothing really helpful...

When i click the button to send the form, noting appears and the page just reloads (it's the action attribute i think), and I don't see the insert in the DB.

Comment: most of your form inputs have `disabled`. Disabled inputs are not sent on form submit, so `if (isset($_POST['exm']) && isset($_POST['series']) && isset($_POST['repetitions']) && isset($_POST['valider'])) ` will be false.

Answer (score 1):

You disabled most of the input fields in your web form and when you click the submit button your script will try to insert empty values in the database. 
However some of your fields are set to `NOT NULL` (like `id_entrainement` for example) and your insert statement won't be executed.

The isset() checks in the beginning should also fail:

```
if (isset($_POST['exm']) && isset($_POST['series']) && isset($_POST['repetitions']) && isset($_POST['valider'])) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bladerz, I think I begin to understand. But what I want is to hide these inputs (I show them to debug). But on the first insert, I don't give the `id_entrainement` in the insert because it's auto-incremnted, and normally I'm allowed to not mention it in the insert. What do you suggest instead of my isset() check? And what I don't mentionned is that the fields are AUTOMATICALLY filled with jQuery that take values in <select>s.

Comment: I think isset is the way to go. The problem is with your form. From what I can see in your table schema only id_exercice is auto incremented. For the rest of the NOT NULL fields you'll need to pass a value. To hide the fields in the form you can just use <input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="your_value">. Just make sure  that "your_value" is not empty.

Comment: Ok I made the changes. I put the NULL value to the not used input, but it's not working again. I don't what to do... I change `$i->bindParam(....,....);` to `$i->bindValue(....,....);` but it doesn't change anything. I even reinstall xampp, but it changes nothing.